# MySQL timestamp is a datetime: shouldn't it be an integer? I need to pass it through the URL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I may be going about this the wrong way, but I have made "previous" and "next" buttons which take you to the next or previous product in the database by passing the index through the URL and getting it with PHP. But I need to accomplish this with the date the products were entered into the database (as indices will be reused if a row is deleted). The problem is I used `datetime` when I first built the database. I would like to convert all those datetimes to timestamps because I understood timestamps would be an integer representing the number of seconds from 1970 or something. An integer is easy to pass through the URL using `get` (no %20 in the URL). But I just tried it in a test database and timestamp isn't just an integer. Am I understanding this wrong? Am I going about it the wrong way?

EDIT: What I really need is a PHP function that will convert a MySQL datetime to a unix timestamp. That will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're understanding it wrong. As a general rule, a SQL timestamp and a Unix timestamp are two different things.

To get a Unix timestamp from a MySQL datetime columns, use the [unix_timestamp() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

Comment: Hmm. Ok, but that function is MySQL. I think what I need is actually a PHP function that converts a MySQL datetime to a unix timestamp. I say this because I want to send a unix timestamp through the url. So at that point I will be doing it with PHP. I'll update the tags to this question.